# Excel Pivot table: Calculated field based on only the first row of a group

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010, pivot-table, calculated-field

I've got the following data and pivot table:

[image]

The **Total** column in the pivot table is the sum of the following calculated field:

```
=start-TIME(7, 30, 0)
```

I know that this calculation is wrong for what I want to achieve. I need to know how much delay I have had on each day to start the work. e.g. on 1-Oct-12, assuming I should have started my work at 7:30, 8:00 - 7:30 which yields 30 minutes delay, 1 hour delay for 2-Oct-12 and 50 minutes for 3-Oct-12.
So my question is, how can I have a calculated field based on only the first row of each group in a pivot table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to avoid calculated fields and do the calculation in the source data if possible.  So in this case I'd add a delay column to your source data, with a calculation that sums the difference only for the first row for each date:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A2)=1,B2-TIME(7,30,0),0)
```

[image]

Then you can pivot on the sum of delay.  Format the delay pivot field like `[h]:mm`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Are you avoiding calculated fields because of performance issues? And, do you think there will be any easy solution using calculated fields?

Comment: No, I don't know of any performance issues.  I just usually find that it's easier to do the calculation in the source data.  That's true for me in this case too: I don't know of any easy solution using calculated fields.

Comment: The COUNTIF solution was very nice. Thank you!